# styling a div in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have this piece of code which creates two divs (leftDiv and rightDiv) inside of an outer div (outerDiv). I want leftDiv to be to the left of rightDiv. This code works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   var outerDiv = document.createElement('div') ;
   var leftDiv = document.createElement('div') ;
   var rightDiv = document.createElement('div') ;

   outerDiv.id = 'outerDiv' ;
   outerDiv.className = 'myClass' ;
   leftDiv.id = 'leftDiv' ;
   rightDiv.id = 'rightDiv' ;
   leftDiv.style.border = '1px solid #000' ;
   rightDiv.style.border = '1px solid #000' ;

   document.body.insertBefore(outerDiv, document.body.firstChild);
   outerDiv.appendChild(leftDiv) ;
   outerDiv.appendChild(rightDiv) ;

   leftDiv.innerHTML='this is left div' ;
   rightDiv.innerHTML='this is right div' ;
}
</script>
<style>
.myClass div {
   float: left ;
   clear: none ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But, I want to do the styling in javascript. So, I want the float:left and the clear:none to be defined in the javascript function. I would expect this to work:

```
outerDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
outerDiv.style.clear = 'none';
```

So, I replace the javascript function with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   var outerDiv = document.createElement('div') ;
   var leftDiv = document.createElement('div') ;
   var rightDiv = document.createElement('div') ;

   outerDiv.id = 'outerDiv' ;
   outerDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
   outerDiv.style.clear = 'none';
   leftDiv.id = 'leftDiv' ;
   rightDiv.id = 'rightDiv' ;
   leftDiv.style.border = '1px solid #000' ;
   rightDiv.style.border = '1px solid #000' ;

   document.body.insertBefore(outerDiv, document.body.firstChild);
   outerDiv.appendChild(leftDiv) ;
   outerDiv.appendChild(rightDiv) ;

   leftDiv.innerHTML='this is left div' ;
   rightDiv.innerHTML='this is right div' ;
}
</script>
```

Firebug shows the  tag that I would expect for the second example so I believe I got the syntax right.

```
<div id="outerDiv" style="float: left; clear: none;">
```

But, the second piece of HTML gives me two divs stacked vertically as if my float and clear are not really taking effect.

What am I doing wrong? (Yes, I'm sure jquery does this much better but I'd still like to understand what I'm not understanding!)

Comment: Try placing script at the end of your body tag see if that works or create Fiddle please.

Comment: @Teemu cssFloat does exists, please research before you comment. Link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're styling the outer div, not the inner divs

```
leftDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
leftDiv.style.clear = 'none';

rightDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
rightDiv.style.clear = 'none';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/HKLQ2/)

The CSS targets all DIV ***within*** `.myClass`, you're setting the JS styles ***on*** `.myClass`

```
.myClass div {
   float: left ;
   clear: none ;
}
```

is not the same as

```
var outerDiv = document.createElement('div') ;

outerDiv.className = 'myClass' ;
outerDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
outerDiv.style.clear = 'none';
```

Comment: Thanks for the education. I imagined it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

It is because JS makes style to one element (outer) ONLY.
CSS is inherited and affects left and right childs while JS method not.